# FastSearchListView [Custom ListView with search function] is taking fullscreen of the view

Tags: android, listview

I have implemented a `FastSearchListView` following instructions in this [link](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/12/android-listview-sectionindexer-fastscroll.html) . I have to implement a `ListView` and a `Button`. But this `ListView` is occupying the whole view and my `Button` is not displayed. I have tried even putting both widgets inside `Linear Layout` and applied weights. Nothing works.
Here  is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="in.nuventure.com.wedding.InviteActivityFragment">

     <FastSearchListView android:id="@+id/invite_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/contact_invitefriends_textView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/invite_send_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/buttons_padding_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/buttons_padding_vertical"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/buttons_padding_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/buttons_padding_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/button_green"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sub_textSize"
            android:text="@string/invite_friends"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you have set it to match_parent that's why it is taking fullscreen

Comment: I did try it with wrap content . But no use

Comment: try aligning your listview above your textview

Comment: how?did you mean `android:layout_above="@+id/invite_listView" ` ? I tried it already. It doesn't work

Comment: no I mean `android:layout_above="@+id/invite_send_button` in your FastListview

Comment: try removing all your padding once.

Comment: i have tried all those. I think it is the issue with Listview Class